# Relation between map function and mathematical concept of map

Tags: functional-programming, mapping, categories

I started reading "conceptual mathematics: an introduction in Category Theory". There, a map is defined as having a domain and codomain, with exactly one arrow leaving a given element of the domain and mapping it to an element in the codomain.

However, my concurrent endeavours in Haskell show the map function (without filtering) to map everything in domain tot everything in codomain.

This leads me to state that the map function in and by itself does not generate correct maps in the mathematical sense. Am i correct in stating this?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics) There are many mathematical concepts called 'map', with different meanings depending on the branch of maths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the similar name, `map` is not the concept of functions/maps. That is, not all functions are some special case of `map`. They're just distinct things that happen to share a name. Happens all the time.

However, `map` is particular a function/map (domain `a -> b`, codomain `[a] -> [b]`), and `map f` for any `f` is a function/map (domain `[a]`, codomain `[b]`).